# Align input points with multiple variable lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to align multiple input points where the input prompt lengths vary considerably.

The code I am using is:

```py
Courses_Names = ["Intro to Programming", "Databases", "Computer Architecture", "Ethics in Computer Science", "Advanced Programming", "Puzzles and Problem Solving"] # Create the Course_Names list
Grades = []
lMax = max(Courses_Names, key=len)                                                          # Variable that determines the longest course name

Name = input("\nPlease input the student's name:\t" )                               # Ask the user to input the student's name

k = 0                                                                               # Iterable variable for counting through the Course_Names list

while k <= len(Courses_Names) - 1:                                                  # While k is less than the number of items in the Course_Names list
    try:
        lX = lMax - len(Courses_Names[k])                                           # Determine the offset for the characters
        Grade = int(input('{:>5s}'.format("Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for %s:\t" % Courses_Names[k], x = lX)))     # Request the user to input a grade for the student, for each module, and converts to an integer

    except ValueError:                                                              # Error/exception handling
        print("Sorry, I did not understand that entry.\n")          
        continue

    if Grade < 0 or Grade > 100:                                                    # Number inputted that is outside the range requested
        print("Sorry, that number is outside of the range allowed.\n")              # Tells the user that the number is invalid
        continue

    else:                                                                           
        Grades.append(Grade)                                                        # Add each valid grade the user entered into the Grades list
        k += 1
```

This results in:

> Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Intro to
> Programming:  95
>
> Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Databases:  85
>
> Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Computer
> Architecture: 75
>
> Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Ethics in
> Computer Science: 65
>
> Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Advanced
> Programming:  55
>
> Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Puzzles and
> Problem Solving:  45

I have tried replacing the input prompts with:

```py
    lX = lMax - len(Courses_Names[k])                                           # Determine the offset for the characters
    try:
        Grade = int(input('{:<5s}{>{x}s}'.format("Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for %s:\t" % Courses_Names[k], x = lX)))     # Request the user to input a grade for the student, for each module, and converts to an integer
```

But this causes triggers the `except ValueError` message on a repeat loop.

I am trying to align the above so that the numbers are all in a vertical alignment one tab length from the longest input prompt.

Comment: Your attempt to replace the input prompts results in evaluating `'{:<5s}{>{x}s}'.format("Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for Intro to Programming:", x = lX)`, which gives `ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a format string, you could define

```py
Course_Name_Format = "{:>" + str(max(len(n) for n in Courses_Names)) + "s}"
```

and then use that in your loop (which, by the way, doesn't seem to need the index `k`):

```
for Course_Name in Courses_Names:
  try:
    Prompt = "Input score between 0 and 100 (no decimal places) for " \
             + Course_Name_Format.format(Course_Name) + ":\t"
    Grade = int(input(Prompt))  

  # ...
```

Comment: Worked almost perfectly. Had to change the ":>" to ":<" but otherwise brilliant. Thank you.